# Setting tabindex on <html:select> Struts tag

Tags: jsp, struts-1, struts1

I need to set a `tabindex` attribute on a html `<select>` dropdown menu that is generated with the`<html:select>` Struts JSP tag. However, it doesn't look like a `tabindex` attribute exists for this tag. Is there a way to somehow add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `JavaScript` or `JQuery` to bind certain attributes to your form elements which are rendered using some JSP tags that do not offer those attributes out of the box:

```js
$("#id1").attr('tabindex', '2');
```

OR

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("id1")[0].setAttribute("tabindex", "2");
```

**Edit**:

I see your edit in the question. So your `select` tag is actually from `struts` tag library. This tag does offer `tabindex` attribute. See these [struts docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like there *is* a tabindex for this tag.

https://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/select.html